# HTML - non-breaking space between text and image

Tags: html

So I have a menu where each (multiline) item has an image rightarrow.png right after the last word of the menu item. The problem is sometimes this arrow goes into a newline by itself, and I want to stop that from happening. I tried

```
Blah blah&nbsp;<img src="rightarrow.png" />
```

but still in some cases it looks like

```
Blah blah
>
```

It's driving me crazy.

Comment: add the full code you have done

Comment: You might need to show more code, especially the CSS. A JSFiddle would be ideal.

Comment: Seriously? Do I have to include the php error log just to be thorough? Come on, how do I ensure that there is never not in any circumstances a breaking space between an image and text in an element where there should be breaking spaces otherwise.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Put all your text in an element, then put the image in another wrapper. Add `white-space:nowrap` to their parent.

Comment: Will there be breaking spaces between words? Because I only need to not be a breaking space between an image and the preceding word.

Comment: @L84 If you set a width on the text container, spaces will break to new lines.

Comment: No, id doesn't break, it's all in one line - probably because white-space:nowrap is in effect

Comment: @L84 You need to reset the wrap property on the text container. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/6Z4Xw/

Comment: Aaah yes, now it works, thanks. Never would've thought of that!

Comment: Addition: id didn't work for me (`span` with `span` + `svg` inside) until I set `display: inline-block` for nested elements

Answer (score 7):

This is the method that works across browsing situations:

```
Blah <nobr>blah <img src="rightarrow.png" /></nobr>
```

The `nobr` tag never got to HTML specs, for some odd reason, but this does not prevent it from working. If you just have to comply with the specs, use clumsier CSS instead:

```
Blah <span style="white-space: nowrap">blah <img src="rightarrow.png" /></span>
```

Comment: Good answer, but accepted is better for the case of using html templates (e.g. when text substitutes on rendering).
Hope, you got my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [BIN](http://jsbin.com/evecud/1/edit). 
I made this after assuming this is what you need.

HTML

```
  <ul>
<li><p>Menu 1</p> <img src="http://www.eurotunnel.com/uploadedImages/commercial/back-steps-icon-arrow.png" align="right"/></li>
<li><p>Menu 2</p> <img src="http://www.eurotunnel.com/uploadedImages/commercial/back-steps-icon-arrow.png" align="right"/></li>
<li><p>Menu 3</p> <img src="http://www.eurotunnel.com/uploadedImages/commercial/back-steps-icon-arrow.png" align="right"/></li>
<li><p>Menu 4</p> <img src="http://www.eurotunnel.com/uploadedImages/commercial/back-steps-icon-arrow.png" align="right"/></li>
  </ul>
```

Css

```
ul{ list-style-type:none;}
ul li{ float:left; padding:10px; width:100px;}
img{ width:20px;height:20px; float:left;}
p{ float:left; margin:0px; }
```

Check [here](http://vivekdragon.wordpress.com/) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Add a `position: absolute;` rule to the image; It will be displayed as if its inline if you don't add left/right positioning to it.

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty is that the NBSP seems to only "bind" to the following entity if the entity is text, and not an image element.

A solution I found if you know the size of the image is to add several NBSPs to the end of the text, and then place a negative margin on the following image, so that it occupies the space of the NBSPs. That way, the last word and the NBSPs constitute one unit that will wrap or not wrap all together, and if the icon is at a negative margin that is greater than the width of the NBSPs, then it will never get pushed to the next line before the last word of the previous text does.

Something like this should work:

```
<span>This is some text&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;><img style="margin-left: -15px;">
```

Alternatively, you can add padding to the text and a negative margin:

```
<span style="padding-right: 15px;">This is some text</span><img style="margin-left: -15px;">
```

(This is based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25857961/5899236)