# No line break between text and SVG

Tags: css, html, svg

I have a short text that is followed by an SVG in a limited-width container. 
The expected behaviour is that the text breaks if it's longer than the container width BUT I would like it NOT to break right between the text and the svg:

**Current result:**
[image: Current result:]

**Expected result:**
[image]

Adding a `<nobr>` or a `<span>`tag in the middle of the text (before blue) and closing it after the SVG is not an option as the text comes from an external database and cannot be edited.

```
<span class="text">
    Jack Wolfskin Jacke Colorado Flex - Midnight Blue
</span>
<span class="svg">
    <svg>
    ....
    </svg>
</span>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can prevent the line breaking with this markup. It doesn't need to include the last word, so you can use it even with a generated content.

##### JSX

```
<div>
  {children}
  <span className="tail">
      {'\u00a0'}
      <svg></svg>
  </span>
</div>
```

##### HTML

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit<span class="tail">&nbsp;<svg></svg></span>
</div>
```

##### CSS

```css
.tail {
  white-space: nowrap;  
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/radarfox/65h40jt7/

Comment: Nice solution. Need to trim white spaces by the end of generated content, though it's not that painful. It helped me to add zero-width non-breaking spaces (U+FEFF) each side of <svg..>

Comment: Excellent solution, you can also use a zero-width space (`&#8203;`) if you want to prevent wrapping without creating any visible space.

Answer (score 4):

The only solution I found required a nasty change in the origin HTML.

To make sure the icon is never alone in the new line I wrapped the last word and the icon in a new element with `white-space: no-wrap;`, plus if we want it to still split if the line cannot accommodate last word with the icon we can make this new container inline flex and flex-wrappable.

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit
  <span class="last_word">
      very_long_last_word
      <svg>...</svg>
  </span>
</div>
```

```css
.last_word {
  /* Stick icon to last word */
  white-space: no-wrap;  
  
  /* Make sure last word and icon will break ultimately */
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
}
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/uerzo6sa/

Answer (score 4):

I combined solutions from the answers above to create this CSS class. It uses a zero-width space instead of a non-breaking one, which is added using CSS. As a result, the HTML looks cleaner and more predictable, without visible extra space.

## CSS

```css
.tail-icon {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.tail-icon::before {
  content: "\200B";
}
```

## HTML

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit<span class="tail-icon"><svg></svg></span>
</div>
```

Example: https://codepen.io/yozi-developer/pen/KKbWmqR

Comment: @Peter Could you share your example?

Comment: Good question, I don't manage to recreate that situation anymore now. I'll remove my comment.

Answer (score 2):

add display-block to svg container:

```
.svg {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: That's not the issue, the svg is already next to the text. The problem is when the text is long enough to push it to the next line

Comment: 1. You can put .text and .svg into container and apply `white-space: nowrap` to it.

Comment: 2. Put the non-breaking space between .text and .svg: `&nbsp;`

Comment: nbsp doesn't work between the text and an svg element for some reason, and the nowrap option will only suffice in single-line instances (seems fine for op).  **Edit:** wrapping the last part of the text and svg in a <span> with nowrap works great.

Comment: NBSPs and a negative margin for the svg seems to work, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can define `position: absolute` on the SVG, with `auto` for `top`, `right`, etc.

https://codepen.io/jsit/pen/xxOQoVW

The only side-effect is this will allow the SVG to appear outside of the containing box; this is in a sense the reason it works at all.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add padding to the text and a negative margin:

```
<span class="text" style="padding-right: 15px;">
    Jack Wolfskin Jacke Colorado Flex - Midnight Blue
</span>
<span class="svg" style="margin-left: -15px;">
    <svg>
    ....
    </svg>
</span>
```

That way, if there isn't room for the padding, the last word will get pushed to the next line also.

(This is based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25857961/5899236)

Comment: Still wraps the icon to the next line, and then places it too far to the left.

Comment: @Peter Works for me, do you have an example? What happens when you increase the padding? In chrome dev tools you can do inspect element and hover over the text element and make sure the padding is larger than the icon so that when you put the negative padding on the icon it sits within the padding of the previous element

Comment: Sorry, I see now that this only happens when the last word is wider than the container. Not really the fault of this solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I have been using:

```css
svg {
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  margin-left: -1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  Quisque eros mi, accumsan quis egestas vitae, auctor eu
  metus. Donec aliquet dolor elementum mauris
  tincidunt.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path fill="none" stroke=currentColor d="M20 20l-7 -7a5 5 0 1 1 .1 -.1" class=""></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

A few remarks though:

- The negative `margin-left` in the CSS equals the width of the icon.
- The amount of distance between text and icon is controlled by the number of `&nbsp;` used. So this distance is not controlled from CSS.
- It is vital that there is no whitespace (no newlines) between the last word, each of the `&nbsp;`s, and the opening `<svg>` tag.