# How to prevent CSS from displaying the ::after content on a new line?

Tags: css

I'm trying to display a list of names, separated by a comma, using CSS:

```css
a:after {
  content: ', \00a0';
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="foo.com">Foo</a>
<a href="bar.com">Bar</a>
```

The problem is that the result looks something like this:

```
Foo, Baz
, Bar
```

Comment: I'm not sure I got the question, do you need to remove `:after` on last `a` element? Also, comma and space do not look underlined.

Comment: If you look at my edit on your question (maybe accept it) you will see there actually is no underline decoration on your `:after` portion. I don't understand why you keep rejecting the edit...

Comment: The underline decoration is only there when I use ```inline```, not ```inline block```. I only added that to explain why I don't use ```inline```.

Comment: It works with inline-block too. If you just could accept my edit, you will see it by yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [prevent :after element from wrapping to next line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100956/prevent-after-element-from-wrapping-to-next-line)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `white-space: nowrap;` to your *a* element into the css in order to prevent the comma displaying alone in the next line.

```css
a {
 white-space: nowrap;
}

a:after {
  content: ', \00a0';
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="foo.com">Foo</a>
<a href="bar.com">Bar</a>
<a href="foo.com">Foo</a>
<a href="bar.com">Bar</a>
<a href="foo.com">Foo</a>
<a href="bar.com">Bar</a>
<a href="foo.com">Foo</a>
<a href="bar.com">Bar</a>
<a href="foo.com">Foo</a>
<a href="bar.com">Bar</a>
<a href="foo.com">Foo</a>
<a href="bar.com">Bar</a>
<a href="foo.com">Foo</a>
<a href="bar.com">Bar</a>
<a href="foo.com">Foo</a>
<a href="bar.com">Bar</a>
<a href="foo.com">Foo</a>
<a href="bar.com">Bar</a>
<a href="foo.com">Foo</a>
<a href="bar.com">Bar</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for, I guess:

HTML:

```
<a href="foo.com">Foo</a>
<a href="bar.com">Bar</a>
```

CSS :

```
a:after {
content: ', \00a0';
display: inline-block;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

Text decoration has to be given to a not to a::after

Comment: But I want the root to be underlined, just not the comma and the whitespace.

Comment: You mean the "text" with underline but the "comma and space" without underline. Am I getting it correct?

Comment: Yes. But that's not really the problem, I've already achieved that with using ```inline-block```. I just tried to explain that since this doesn't work with ```inline``` I need to use ```inline-block```.

Comment: When I see the entire communication and the title of this problem, there is a confusion. In short, Is it like why the same thing can not be achieved by "display: inline"?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add some css properties to you a:after and a like shown bellow  :

```
a{
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-decoration: underline
}
a:after {
    content: ',';
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: But I need the names to be displayed accross several lines. I just don't want a linebreak after each name.

Comment: yeah and the solution is what i posted, the comma will never be broken separatelly.

Answer (score 0):

Add these properties to the a selector:

```
display: block;
float: left;
```